# Formatting text in snippet description field

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, textmate, vscode-extensions

It there any way to formatting text inside description field of a snippet?
Basic formatting like \n \t working fine but is there any way for example changing text color or something?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53296517/how-to-write-a-multi-line-description-for-user-snippets-in-vs-code Not for styling the description text but at least multiline descriptions got easier with v.1.31.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think many people need this feature. If you want for example mark some snippet you can use emoji:

```json
"console.log": {
    "prefix": "cl",
    "body": [
        "console.log($1)"
    ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Alex!This is nice. I tried to implement some kind of autocomplete with snippets.Not the best way I know but I don't familiar with typescript so I tried the easiest way.