# How to write a multi-line description for user snippets in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I tried to create my own user snippet for pascal in VS Code.
It worked fine and the multi-line descriptions I wrote were displayed
correctly.
But after a while, like a month, the descriptions with multiple lines aren't working anymore.
The problem may be the code for the multi-line descriptions because descriptions with only one row still works and displays correct.
However the multi-line descriptions aren't displayed correctly and get replaced with a {0} instead of the description I wrote.

This is how the multi-line descriptions are displayed:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B61pT.png]

Instead of my description there is a {0} and I don't know why because it worked fine a month ago.

This is the code I used:

```
{
    "SetValue":{
        "prefix": "SetValue",
        "body": "SetValue(${1:val:Integer}, ${2:id:Integer});",
        "description": [
            "Parameter:\r",
            "  val...desc\r",
            "  id....desc\r",
            "\r",

            "result:\r",
            "  0 : false desc\r",
            "  1 : true desc\r"
        ]
    }
}
```

I hope I have expressed myself understandably and you may can help me with this problem. Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't explain why it changed but it appears to accept only one string (and not an array of strings).  But you can still build up one string - a little ugly but it works:

```
"description":
          "Parameter:\rval...desc\r  id....desc\r\rresult:\r  0 : false desc\r  1 : true desc\r"
```

Now it will display in the suggestions panel as you expect.

**Edit**: v1.31 fixed this so you can use an array of strings rather than one long string.  [Snippet descriptions](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_31#_snippets-descriptions)

> When authoring snippets with long descriptions, in the past you were
> forced to write a long single string. There was no support for using
> an array as you could for body. This has now changed and long
> descriptions can be written using string arrays.

```
{
  "prefix": "happy",
    "body": "#Happy Coding!",
    "description": [
      " First Line",    // note the spaces after the opening parens
      " Second Line",
      " Third Line"
    ]
}
```

Thanks to @Ben questioning this, I found a bug and a fix.

```
    "description": [
      "First Line",    // won't work
      "Second Line",
      "Third Line"
    ]

    "description": [
      " First Line",    // will work
      " Second Line",
      " Third Line"
    ]
```

It won't work if the leading space is only on the `"First Line"`, but will work if there is a leading space on `" Second Line"` **or** `" Third Line"`.  So I suggest just making a leading space on all the lines.

OR better this works:

```
 "description": [
    "First line",        // no leading spaces
    "Second line",
    "Third line",
    "\r"                 // just adding this makes it work, or \n
  ]
```

The OP's example works because there are some leading spaces and a `"\r"` in his description.

[image: long description in a snippet]

---

An issue, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146493, has been filed on this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I thought to do this like you said. I tried your code and it works fine. First I thought there are maybe other ways as the one you meant but I guess this is the only one. However thanks for your reply it's working fine but as you said it's a little bit ugly.